# Git log different behaviour

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a strange behaviour between my laptop ang gitlab CI. When I execute the following command `git log -1 --date=short index.html` on my laptop it display the last commit for the file.

```
git log -1 --date=short index.html
commit 5df9780d5431fd8efe6ba968ea74090a0189a228
Author: test <jenkins@test.com>
Date:   2021-03-31

    Commit for index.html
```

Whereas when I execute the command in .gitlab-ci.yml when pipeline is executed I have the last commit for the whole repo and not only for the index.html file.

```
git log -1 --date=short index.html
commit 55b13a77fb7e081dc4531e040f3c2c227c0e6412
Author: test <jenkins@test.com>
Date:   2021-09-07

    Commit for README.md
```

There is somebody which can help me to understand why ? I try to display many different option but the both machine seems to be similar except to display git log history for a file. To complete I work only on master branch and there is not other branch created.

Comment: Use `--` before the path `index.html` to disambiguate between refs and pathspecs. Although I doubt it's the problem here, but it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of two things:

- `git log`, asked for *file* history, fakes it from the only history that actually exists: the *commits* in the repository;
- GitLab CI, asked to clone a repository, often (for good reasons) uses a *shallow* clone, which carries fewer commits = less history.

In particular, the command you ran—`git log -1 --date=short index.html`—tells `git log`:

- Start at the current, or `HEAD`, commit.  Put this commit into the to-be-visited queue.
- Now, for each commit in the queue (in a loop, with commits being removed from the queue in priority order to loop over them—but initially there's only one commit anyway):

  - Examine the commit.  Load its saved source tree, and the saved source tree of the immediately-previous or *parent* commit or commits.  (Merge commits are those with two or more parents.)  If there *is no* previous commit, e.g., this is the very *first* commit, load up an ["empty tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) for the saved parent tree.
  - If, in comparing the file `index.html` as saved in *this* commit, to the file `index.html` as saved in the *parents* (or fake empty tree), there's some *difference* in this file, mark this commit as "to be printed out".  This difference can be a change in the file (if it's in both saved snapshots), or a change in its existence (here in this commit, gone in the parent, for instance).
  - Place the parent or parents into the queue.
  - If we're to *print* this commit, print it with `--date=short`, and then quit (`-1`).

That's the end of the loop.  So what happens is that we print the first commit that *changes the one specified file* in some way, e.g., creates it initially (it wasn't in the parent) or modifies it (it's in both commits but is different in the two snapshots).

Merge commits here are tricky and generally don't get printed by this process (you can modify this behavior with additional `git log` flags).  They do, however, push multiple parents into the queue, which makes the priority-queue aspect matter.  But merge commits are probably a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) here.  Instead, let's talk a bit more about *shallow clones*.

To make a shallow clone, a Git client (the `clone` operation is run as a client) asks a server to *stop* sending commits after some point.  That is, the server says, e.g., that the latest commit is `badc0ffee`, so the client says *give me that commit*.  The server then says that the commit before `badc0ffee` is `deadcafe` but the client says: *Oh, I only want one commit, don't give me `deadcafe` after all*.

So, the server *doesn't*.  The client, to remember that while there's some parent `deadcafe` for commit `badc0ffee`, stores the hash ID `deadcafe` in a *shallow grafts* database.  When the client encounters a reference to commit `deadcafe`, it pretends that commit doesn't exist and that there was no such reference.

The result is that `git log -1`, run on the client that made this one-commit shallow clone, thinks that the one commit *in* the shallow clone is *the only commit ever*.  The file `index.html` exists in that last commit, and because there's no parent—the shallow-ness effectively effaces the parent—it was *created in that commit*.  So it's different from the empty tree, and `git log -1` will print out the hash ID and metadata from that last commit.

If we make a shallow clone that's two commits deep, we'll have both `badc0ffee` and `deadcafe`, but the parent of `deadcafe`—let's say it's `cabbabb1e`—will be cut off.  If we run `git log -1 index.html` here, Git will first compare `index.html` in `badc0ffee` vs `index.html` in `deadcafe`.  If those are *different*, `git log` will print commit `badc0ffee` (and then quit, because of the `-1`).  If not, Git will move on to commit `deadcafe`.  Since its parent `cabbabb1e` is cut off via the shallow clone, `git log` will believe that commit `deadcafe` *created* `index.html` and will print out *that* commit (and then quit).

#### Conclusion

You need to know what a shallow clone is, when to use it, and when *not* to use it.  You may need to make your GitLab setup produce a less-shallow, or not-at-all shallow, clone to get whatever effect you desire here.